# iOS:Objective -C How to change push notification sound payload when app in background mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, push-notification, background

In my application i am allowing user to change a sound for `push notification`.

When user selects `Sound-A` or `Sound-B` it plays properly when app is in active mode.

But when app is in `background mode` it always plays `Sound-A` because `push notification payload sound` is set to `Sound-A.`

```
{
   "aps": {
   "alert": "My News!",
   "sound": "sound_a.mp3",
    }
 }
```

How can i overwrite it with users selected sound.

I have stored users selected sound in `app preferences` and i tried with replacing it, but it is not working.

```
NSString *soundName = [self getSoundTrack];
[pushArray setObject:soundName forKey:@"sound"];
```

Comment: You need to set the sound name in payload.

Comment: Is it possible to change sound name programmatically?

Comment: Well I am not sure, but as far as my knowledge is concerned you cannot set it programmatically. You need added sound file in your app bundle and payload should have that file name in "sound" key.

Answer (score 1):

you can play notification sound in background using AVplayer..working fine in my app

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;


 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
 _audioPlayer=nil;
  if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground ){
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@“soundName”
                                     ofType:@"mp3"]];
NSError *error;
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                initWithContentsOfURL:url
                error:&error];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
    [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
}
[_audioPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: how can i change "soundName" as per users selection when app is in background mode?

Comment: you need to manage "soundname" on your end....i am randomly playing sound on every notification.. i have 40 sounds files

Comment: have you added sound file in your app bundle ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not change sound from your ios app, when receiving in background mode. The sound to be played is sent in payload. If you want play sound which user selected, you should be able to store that data in backend as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programmatically change the sound using iOS client code, you can instead have the server send a silent push notification, then send a local notification with the configured sound when your app is woken up into the background.

However, the simpler solution is what others are saying. Update the server when a user changes their sound settings.